# how can I expire an action (set with caches :action) from the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, console

I'd like to be able to expire an action cache at will from the console. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. Rails 3.

This is what I've tried so far: http://pastebin.com/1f4RhqnP

Answer (score 0):

while it would help to include the exact line of caches action code, you should be able to use expire_action.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html#method-i-expire_action

Since action caching actually uses fragment caching underneath, you should be able to use expire_fragment as well.  Try using the _url or _path helper methods to generate the key you're trying to expire, instead of individual options.